# Postgresql: How to append unique rows from a temp table to an existing table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Basically I am copying unique rows from a table t2 before deleting all the rows and finally inserting the unique rows from the temp table t1.

```
//copy unique rows to temp table t1
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (select distinct on (name) * from t2);

//delete rows from t2
DELETE FROM t2;

//paste the unique rows from temp table
insert into t2(name, age, grade)
select name, age, grade
from t1;
```

However, I am not sure if I am going about this the efficient way? Is there another SQL query that can strip a table so that only the unique rows remain? Or is my sql shown makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is probably the best way -- queries that modify lots of rows in a table are often slower than emptying the table and re-inserting the rows.

You do have to be careful.  Your code will be more efficient with an index on `name`.  Also, `identity`/`serial` columns and other automatically assigned columns might need special care.

If we assume that the table has a unique id, then you can do something like:

```
delete from t1
    where t1.id > (select max(tt1.id)
                   from t1 tt1
                   where tt1.name = t1.name
                  );
```